# How to stop Edge browser opening Chrome tabs when it starts

Tags: microsoft-edge

Every time I start Edge browser in Windows 10, if Chrome is open with a few tabs, Edge automatically opens all of them. This is quite annoying. Has anyone encountered this before and knows how to make Edge behave?

Comment: This does not happen to me and I have both browsers.  Try tuning Sync OFF for both browsers and restart. You can always turn back on the Sync you need. Check browser extensions - I do not use these.

Comment: Which browser is your default browser?

Comment: I disabled Profile->Sync->Open tabs in Edge, Edge still does the same. Default browser is Chrome

Comment: Happens with me also, and I'm frustrated by this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. In a new tab, open the page edge://settings/profiles/importBrowsingData.
2. Click on Import browser data on each launch.
3. Turn off Import browser data from Google Chrome on each launch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Man this is frustrating.  I have turned off these sync options as indicated, and Edge is still opening my Chrome tabs when launching Edge.